# react-native cant run ios device

Tags: ios, react-native, device

I try to run react-native app on a ios real device.
It works well on simulator or on a device using xcode but I would like to run with command-line
I tried this :

```
>npm install -g ios-deploy 

>react-native run-ios --device "My iPhone"
```

And this is what I get :

```
info Found Xcode workspace "Project.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Project.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Project -destination id=00008020-0001395426EA002E")
......................................................................
2020-04-06 11:15:02.836 xcodebuild[16724:402803]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008020-0001395426EA002E was NULL
2020-04-06 11:15:02.967 xcodebuild[16724:402797]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008020-0001395426EA002E was NULL
info Installing and launching your app on My iPhone
```

The app appears in my iPhone but doesnt run.

Metro oppens in a new terminal but I get only this :

```
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               

                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

And I doesnt get the progress bar that shows on build with XCode.

**EDIT**

For the logs :

```
user@MBP Project % react-native log-ios
error No active iOS device found
```

Versions installed :

```
user@MBP Project % react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.0
```

Comment: try runnig using xcode run, does it still doesnt run

Comment: It does run on xcode but I try using command line

Comment: check the logs in terminal
```$ react-native log-ios
$ react-native log-android```

Comment: what's your react-native version?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score -1):

**If you only want to run the app at the device, try this steps:**

1 - In Xcode, add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences.

2 - Go to Product > Destination > select your device.

3 - Go to Schema > Edit schema... > at your left side, click at "Run".

4 - At Info, select "Release" at "Build Configuration".

5 - Close the window and click at "Start the Active Schema".

Xcode installs the app on the device before launching the app, trust the developer at iPhone and enjoy.

Answer (score -4):

```
enter code here in terminal
```

```
react-native run-ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro Max”
```