# development Server isn't starting

Tags: react-native

i am facing this issue for quite some times. i've created a  new project but while starting the server by typing `npm start` or `react-native start` in terminal i am getting this output instead of starting server. While in old project development server started successfully. Can anybody tell what's the problem here?

The output when i try to run my project is:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s info Connecting to the development server... error Failed to install the app on the device. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

[image]

here is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "ReduxDemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt seems like it's an error. You can't run the project even with this output?

Comment: Here is the output.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
info Connecting to the development server...
error Failed to install the app on the device. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: I see you're on linux, right? Try running `sudo npm start`, on a terminal maybe.

Comment: No Luck, i already tried

Comment: Try running thison your project folder, before running `sudo npm start`:
`sudo chmod 755 android/gradlew`

Comment: Again NO luck. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: When you run `adb devices` your device appears on the list, right?

Comment: yes, i even tried `react-native run-android --deviceId=DEVICE_ID` but the problem is my development server isn't starting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211070/discussion-between-parth-and-wiliam-brochensque-junior).

Comment: There's a similar issue asked 4 hours ago, maybe it's an error with react-native itself.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056762/react-native-cant-run-ios-device

Comment: what's your react-native version?

Comment: it's done. I opened project in android studio and run the application from there. then i run the command `npm run android` and it's working like a charm. Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: Well, i really don't know what happened, but in the end everything worked!
That's what matters